# can't use wine- version mismatch error

Tags: linux-mint, wine

Can't fix wine version mismatch error. this is what i get:

```
wine client error:0: version mismatch 648/650.
Your wineserver binary was not upgraded correctly,
or you have an older one somewhere in your PATH.
Or maybe the wrong wineserver is still running?
```

All the solution i found were about closing an older wine version still running. I have only one version installed (as much as i know) and it doesn't start because of this error. linux mint sylvia, cinnamon desktop. wine version 5.19 (staging), i get an error when i try to remove.

I have no idea why or when did this error begin.

Comment: Uninstall it, and reinstall from the repository.

Comment: please add distro, what you did to get this error, and what you have tried to fix it. (to help people in the future searching this post).

Comment: edited the post with a distro. can't remove, it says 'Virtual packages like 'wine64' can't be removed'
I'm running wine-5.18 staging.

Comment: removed with ^wine, reinstalled but still the same error but with different numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- First, uninstall anything "wine" that you can.
- Then run: `sudo apt purge "*wine*"` (exactly as typed)
- To see if you have any wine packages still installed, run this:
  `dpkg -l "*wine*" | grep ii`
- If there are "left over" wine packages they'll be marked as unneeded and can be removed with `sudo apt-get autoremove`

**You should be ready to party now** and your wine packages *should* (fingers crossed) no longer be borked.

I already had a hunch on how to fix this but [this page](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=316725) confirmed my suspicions.

Please let me know if this works.

Comment: I did that (actually before i saw your answer), and than i did it 3 more times. finally it took, i don't know why.